# What's inside the CPU?

Tags: cpu, photos

Where can I see some pictures of how the CPU looks from inside?

Comment: You realize the current CPUs use feature sizes of 45nm or less. By comparison, the wavelength of visible light is between 380 to 750nm. In other words, the average size of the discrete elements on a CPU is around 10 times smaller than the light waves used by human vision. They are too small to see. But if you just want pics of the image returned in visible light, then try using Google image search.

Comment: Be sure that I googled before posting here, anyway, was really interesting reading your comment indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean photographs, Google Images search for [microprocessor die](http://www.google.com/images?hl=en&safe=active&gbv=2&tbs=isch%3A1&sa=1&q=microprocessor+die&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

If you mean on a logical level, you'll need to understand some digital logic and computer architecture. UA has a [course on digital logic](http://jjackson.eng.ua.edu/courses/ece380/lectures/) online, which will tell you what the building blocks are.  For architecture, I would recommend the book by [Hennessey and Patterson](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558605967), having used it in the past.

If you want block diagrams, searching around will be your best bet, e.g. one of a [Pentium](http://www.laynetworks.com/block%20diagram%20of%20the%20pentium.htm) and one of a [Xeon](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~euroben/reports/web07/xeon.html). But I don't think these will be very useful unless you have a decent understanding of digital logic and architecture first.

Comment: Yes, I meant photographs, I just didn't know about the 'microprocessor die' term. thanks.